# Copy paste the content of a URL

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python programming and currently stuck while implementing a scenario where I need to copy the contents of a URL (similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the URL result, and pasting in to a text file) in to a string variable. This URL user's to log in with their credentials as it's an intranet site.

Comment: It is not too clear what you are asking. Could you be more clear exacty what you want the program to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: For example, if I want to read the content of an URL 'https://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/rj.txt', then below code can be used. 

>>import requests
>>res = requests.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/rj.txt')
>>res.status_code == requests.codes.ok
>>print(res.text)

But if I do the same for the URL https://www.google.co.in/'(which is not txt) then the output is some kind of a script , where as I am looking for an output similar to the first one which prints just the text present in the URL front end. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The output I am expecting is as below when I request the google.co.in URL.
Gmail
Images
Sign in
Google
India
Google.co.in offered in: हिन्दी বাংলা తెలుగు मराठी தமிழ் ગુજરાતી ಕನ್ನಡ മലയാളം ਪੰਜਾਬੀ 
Privacy Terms Settings 
Advertising Business About

Comment: Ah yeah, chances are there is some java script that helps render that page. You would have to use a library that can execute javascript/wait for page to load fully. The simplest one I have used is ghost. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) library. Here is a simple example:

```
import ghost

g = ghost.Ghost()
url = 'http://www.google.co.in'

with g.start() as session:
    page, extra_resources = session.open(url)

if page.http_status != 200:
    print('Error: Unexpected http_status from ghost')

print(page.content)
```

Comment: Thanks Igor for the response. I installed ghost library using the command pip install ghost.py. When I tried executing g = ghost.Ghost(), it resulted in an exception 'Ghost.py requires PySide or PyQt4'. Exception as below is thrown when I tried to install Pyside using the command 'pip install -U Pyside'.

complete output from command python setup/py egg_info:
only these versions of python are supported: [<2,6>,<2,7>,<3,2>,<3,3>,<3,4>]
command "python setup.py eg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\swed\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-8m3iu55b\pyside

Comment: I installed PySide same way and didn't have a problem. What version of python are you running? Use `python -V` command to see. You can can also try installing PyQt4 and see if that works.

Comment: Also, I don't use the -U uption since that is used for upgrading already installed packages. Try `python -m pip install PySide`.